# Python output every nth row without Pandas

Tags: python, csv

I'm really new to Python and my task is to rewrite a CSV with Python. I managed to program a working script for my task already. Now I would like to get only every 10th row of the CSV as output.
Is there an easy way to do this?
I already tried to use Jason Reeks answer.
Now it works, thank you!

```
import csv
import sys

userInputFileName = sys.argv[1]
outPutFileSkipped = userInputFileName.split('.')[0] + '-Skipped.csv'

cnt = 0
first = True

with open(outPutFileSkipped, 'w', newline='') as outputCSV:
    csv_reader_object_skipped = csv.reader((x.replace('\0', '') for x in open(userInputFileName)), delimiter=',')
    csv_writer_object_skipped = csv.writer(outputCSV, delimiter=',')

    for row, line in enumerate(csv_reader_object_skipped):
        if row % 10 == 0:
            print(line)
            csv_writer_object_skipped.writerow(line)

print('Es wurden erfolgreich ' + str(cnt) + ' Zeilen formatiert!')
```

Comment: Hi @Alex, could you provide a bit more details? Some example of your input data, what the output should look like and your current code would be very useful

Comment: Input data is 
Longitude, Latitude, datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a native way to do it without pandas:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row, line in enumerate(reader):
        # Depending on your reference point you may want to + 1 to row 
        # to get every 10th row.
        if row % 10 == 0:  
            print(line)
```

Comment: Thank you! It just says "_csv.Error: iterable expected, not int"

Answer (score -2):

There's an easy way with Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": range(100), "b": range(100, 200)})
df.loc[::10]
```

Comment: **without** Pandas

Comment: Thank you! I just started to write the programme without Pandas, so I would prefer a solution without..